# DateTime.Parse ignoring my IFormatProvider?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime

It looks to me like .NET is ignoring the TwoDigitYearMax property of the CultureInfo (IFormatProvider) I pass for parsing?

Specifically, I cannot explain why the last line of this says 1930, and not 2030. Can anyone reproduce or explain it?

Windows 7, .NET 4.0, en-US system settings.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace DateTimeParse
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax);
            Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("1/1/30"));
            CultureInfo myCI = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("1/1/30", myCI));
            Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Calendar.ToFourDigitYear(30));
            myCI.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2115;
            Console.WriteLine(myCI.Calendar.ToFourDigitYear(30));
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("1/1/30", myCI));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

My results:

```
2029
en-US
1/1/1930 12:00:00 AM
1/1/1930 12:00:00 AM
1930
2030
1/1/1930 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: As an aside, it would be much easier to help you if you'd put this into a short but complete program rather than just an interactive session. We should be able to copy, paste, compile and run. In particular, in trying to come up with a similar short but complete program, it's worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow through the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,3dcde4b72349960c) you'll see that `DateTimeFormatInfo` is extracted from your `CultureInfo` by simply referencing `CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat`.

There is a `Calendar` property on `DateTimeFormatInfo`, which is what is used in parsing. These two are normally the same (i.e. reference equal), the fact you `Clone` your `CultureInfo` results in them being different as each are cloned - you can see that by following through the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,283cdb37a971c697) for `CultureInfo.Clone()`.

You need to change the `Calendar` on the `DateTimeFormatInfo`:

```
var culture = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2115;
```

See a working example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IytEvz

Answer (score 0):

From  the [documentation for twodigityearmax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> This property allows a 2-digit year to be properly translated to a
>   4-digit year. For example, if this property is set to 2029, the
>   100-year range is from 1930 to 2029. Therefore, a 2-digit value of 30
>   is interpreted as 1930, while a 2-digit value of 29 is interpreted as
>   2029.
>
> The initial value of this property is derived from the settings in the
>   regional and language options portion of Control Panel. However, that
>   information can change during the life of the AppDomain. The Calendar
>   class does not detect changes in the system settings automatically. If
>   the calendar is not supported in the regional and language options,
>   the initial value of this property is the default value defined by the
>   Calendar class.
>
> Your application should set this value to 99 to indicate that 2-digit
>   years are to be taken literally. For example, if this property is set
>   to 99, the 100-year range is from 0 (not a valid value for most
>   calendars) to 99. Therefore, a 2-digit value of 30 is interpreted as
>   30.

```
myCI.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2115
2115
```

This gives you the 100-year range from 2016 to 2115

```
myCI.Calendar.ToFourDigitYear(30)
2030
```

So then 30 is the first year 30 within that range.
Namely `2030`